# Ubuntu with Windows. Only Shell showing up?

Tags: windows, ubuntu

Okay, so I have just installed Ubuntu with the Ubuntu Windows Installer. The installation went fine. However now that I've rebooted my pc and I start Ubuntu, only a shell shows up. Something called "Busy box". No window manager is displayed. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you read this? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1785947

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start Gnome Display Manager (of course, with super user privileges):

```
/etc/init.d/gdm start
```

**gdm** can be replaced with **kdm** or **xdm** - it depends on your login manager.

You may also try to type in:

```
startx
```